# i m getting an error on cmd i.e. build.xml doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, cmd

m trying to build my .apk file using cmd command "ant build "
but every it give me same error . and the error is 
[image]

please assist me

Answer (score 4):

There is no build.xml file present in the directory from where you wish to execute the build.

Answer (score 0):

Run `android` tool (found in `sdk/tools` folder) to update the project:

```
android update project -p path/to/project/folder  -n name_of_project -t android-15
```

set target according to android version: `android-10` to `android-17`

Comment: it is updated ....when i run any command on cmd related to ant it give me same error

Comment: @DeepakGupta Can you check that `build.xml` is generated in project folder after you update the project ?

Comment: ya it contain a build.xml file

Comment: @DeepakGupta Try `ant -find build.xml`.